# C# Left join in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

Not sure how to convert the following sql into a LINQ expression. My db does use referential integrity and table Content is related to table Content_Training in a 1 to many relationship (ex: 1 content can have many content_trainings).

```
select c.ContentId, c.Name, ct.TrainingTypeId 
from dbo.Content c left join dbo.ContentTraining ct on c.ContentId = ct.ContentId
where c.ExpirationDate is not null
order by ct.TrainingTypeId, c.Name
```

I have tried this, which seems to work. However, I am not certain about the usage of the "let" keyword.

```
var data = (from c in context.Contents
let ct = ( from t in context.Content_Training where t.ContentId == c.ContentId
select new { t.TrainingTypeId } ).FirstOrDefault()
where c.ExpirationDate.HasValue
orderby ct.TrainingTypeId, c.Name
select new { c.ContentId, c.Name, ct.TrainingTypeId } ).ToList();
```

Comment: @the 8th bit: Added what I have tried so far.

Comment: Your title says "left join" but the SQL you show is doing an inner join, so I'm unclear as to which you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Craig W: Sorry about that. Yes, I do want a left join. I edited my sql.

Comment: did you just ask the exact same question under another username? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951644/c-sharp-left-join-in-a-lambda-expression

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For left join, you need to use DefaultIfEmpty()

Your query should be something similar to this:

```
var query = from c in Content
            join ct in ContentTraining
            on c.ContentId equals ct.ContentId into g
            from ct in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where c.ExpirationDate != null
            select new
            {     
                c.ContentId, 
                c.Name, 
                ct.TrainingTypeId 
             }).ToList();
```

Please refer to [Left outer join in linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971063/left-outer-join-in-linq)

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

Comment: Thank you Rashmi! Regarding Craig W's response below, does "include" do a left join?

Comment: I'm not sure of "Include". Maybe Craig can answer. Did my solution work? I couldn't test it as I don't have VS.Net right now.

Comment: For left join in sql try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75658735/7952953

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you might consider using lambda instead of expression syntax. I haven't tried this but this should get you what you need (if what you need is a left join).

```
var foo = context.Contents.Include( "Content_Training" )
    .Where( c => c.ExpirationDate != null )
    .OrderBy( c => c.Content_Training.TrainingTypeId )
    .ThenBy( c => c.Name
    .Select( c => new { c.ContentId, c.Name, c.Content_Training.TrainingTypeId } );
```

Comment: So "include" does a left join?

Comment: Also, in this case I am interested in the LINQ version. I am unsure about my use of the "let" keyword and wanted some info and opinions on that.

Comment: It's not a left join per se but the results are essentially the same,  if there are no Content_Training objects associated with the Content object you will still get the Content object.