# C# Model Query returns no result because Joins may not have records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a query and I cannot remember. I guess my real question is, Do I need the extra Joins in this query and if yes them how do I handle the fact that Users may not have Posts, Tasks, or Notifications. I know that you can use coalesce but in this instance it doesn't appear to like it. So How do I get a successful Query if no records are found in the tables of the joins.

In the controller I do a redirect

```
if (modelInstance == null)
{
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
}
```

If I remove the joins it will populate the View Page. My guess is because there are no records in these joins - Yet..

Here is my Query:

```
 public class ProfileViewModel
{
    public static ProfileViewModel GetUserProfile(string id, GeneralEntities db)
    {
        var qUser = from usr in db.Users
                    join post in db.Posts on usr.AspNetUsersId equals post.CreatedBy
                    join task in db.Tasks on usr.AspNetUsersId equals task.UsersId
                    join notif in db.Notifications on usr.AspNetUsersId equals notif.UsersId
                    where (usr.AspNetUsersId == id)
                    select new ProfileViewModel
                    {
                        AspNetUsersId = usr.AspNetUsersId,
                        FirstName = usr.FirstName,
                        LastName = usr.LastName,
                        ProfileImage = usr.ProfileImage,
                        Title = usr.Title,
                        Education = usr.Education,
                        Skills = usr.Skills,
                        About = usr.About,
                        IsFemale = usr.IsFemale,
                        IsMale = usr.IsMale,
                        IsStaff = usr.IsStaff
                    };

        var result = qUser.FirstOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            result.PostResults = db.Posts.Where(x => x.CreatedBy == result.AspNetUsersId);
            result.TaskResults = db.Tasks.Where(x => x.UsersId == result.AspNetUsersId);
            result.NotificationResults = db.Notifications.Where(x => x.UsersId == result.AspNetUsersId);
        };

        return result;
    }

    public string UsersId { get; set; }
    public string AspNetUsersId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "F Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "L Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Profile Image")]
    public string ProfileImage { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Job Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Education")]
    public string Education { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Skills")]
    public string Skills { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "About")]
    public string About { get; set; }
    public bool? IsStaff { get; set; }
    public bool? IsMale { get; set; }
    public bool? IsFemale { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Post> PostResults { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Tasks> TaskResults { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Notification> NotificationResults { get; set; }
}
```

I also tried the `.Where(x => x.UserId != null)` but that did not work either.

thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @Scott, for your scenario, you need to apply `LEFT JOIN` to those tables which possibly return no data. For your reference [How to LEFT JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22952403/8017690)

Comment: @YongShun That worked, However I am still wondering if I even need the joins if I am already using an IEnumerable for the result sets on the result.AspNetUserId that i already get from Users??

Comment: Thumbs up! If you use `LEFT JOIN`, you can query out those related `post`, `task`, `notif` in your `.Select()`, then you don't need to have query other result set based on `result.AspNetUsersId`. Alternative solution, your first query will query only User, then query other result set based on `result.AspNetUsersId`.

Answer (score 1):

While you can use `LEFT JOIN` to handle the case where the joined table can have zero-to-many results, the result isn't going to be what you appear to need based on the structure of your `ProfileViewModel` class.

If you always want to return the matching user then a simple query on `db.Users` to get the record is sufficient. You'll end up with 4 queries - one for the user and one each for the related records - but they'll all be quite straight-forward:

```
var usr = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.AspNetUsersId == id);
if (usr == null)
    return null;

return new ProfileViewModel
{
    AspNetUsersId = usr.AspNetUsersId,
    // ...the rest of the usr fields...
    PostResults = db.Posts.Where(x => x.CreatedBy == id),
    // ...and so on.
};
```

Note that since `IQueryable<>` implements `IEnumerable<>` then each time you enumerate over `PostResults`, `TaskResults` or `NotificationResults` you'll be running a query against the database.

Alternatively you could include some extras in your `usr` query to get metrics on the linked tables - number of items for instance, or just a flag saying whether or not they have any linked rows:

```
var usr = 
(
    from usr in db.Users
    where usr.AspNetUsersId == id
    select new
    {
        usr,
        postCount = db.Posts.Count(p => p.CreatedBy == usr.AspNetUsersId),
        hasTasks = db.Tasks.Any(t => t.UsersId == usr.AspNetUsersId),
        hasNotes = db.Notifications.Any(n => n.UsersId == usr.AspNetUsersId),
    }
).FirstOrDefault();
```

That could be useful for reducing the query load later. If there are no posts for instance then assigning an empty array to the `PostResults` field is a good idea. Maybe you want to load all of the posts if there are only a handful rather than have them queried multiple times later.

---

A note since this is ASP.NET: You want to be very careful about those `Results` fields.

Deferred queries are useful, but when they outlive their data context they can cause problems. In a simple MVC view model context you're probably fine, just as long as you understand the risks. For short-term 'fetch and display' this should be perfectly fine, but if the model is stored and reused anywhere then don't save an `IQueryable<>`. Materialize your queries with `ToArray()` or similar in those instances, or explicitly recreate the query against the current data context when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code with the Left joins that @YongShun led me to. I am still wondering if I really need these joins in my current query, Nevertheless if someone can find this useful here it is..

```
public class ProfileViewModel
{
    public static ProfileViewModel GetUserProfile(string id, GeneralEntities db)
    {
        var qUser = from usr in db.Users
                    join post in db.Posts on usr.AspNetUsersId equals post.CreatedBy into a from post in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join task in db.Tasks on usr.AspNetUsersId equals task.UsersId into b from task in b.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join notif in db.Notifications on usr.AspNetUsersId equals notif.UsersId into c from notif in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where (usr.AspNetUsersId == id)
                    select new ProfileViewModel
                    {
                        AspNetUsersId = usr.AspNetUsersId,
                        FirstName = usr.FirstName,
                        LastName = usr.LastName,
                        ProfileImage = usr.ProfileImage,
                        Title = usr.Title,
                        Education = usr.Education,
                        Skills = usr.Skills,
                        About = usr.About,
                        IsFemale = usr.IsFemale,
                        IsMale = usr.IsMale,
                        IsStaff = usr.IsStaff
                    };

        var result = qUser.FirstOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            result.PostResults = db.Posts.Where(x => x.CreatedBy == result.AspNetUsersId);
            result.TaskResults = db.Tasks.Where(x => x.UsersId == result.AspNetUsersId);
            result.NotificationResults = db.Notifications.Where(x => x.UsersId == result.AspNetUsersId);
        };

        return result;
    }

    public string UsersId { get; set; }
    public string AspNetUsersId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "F Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "L Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Profile Image")]
    public string ProfileImage { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Job Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Education")]
    public string Education { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Skills")]
    public string Skills { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "About")]
    public string About { get; set; }
    public bool? IsStaff { get; set; }
    public bool? IsMale { get; set; }
    public bool? IsFemale { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Post> PostResults { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Tasks> TaskResults { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Notification> NotificationResults { get; set; }
}
```